# How to call bean method when clicking on a checkbox

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

What is the appropriate way to call `selectAll` Java method when from bean when I click on a checkbox?

```
<f:facet name="header">
      <h:selectBooleanCheckbox  binding="#{bean.selectAll}" onclick="highlight(this)" class="checkall"/>
</f:facet>
```

`binding` is not working. I just want to execute the code in this Java method.

EDIT

```
private HashMap<String, Boolean> selected = new HashMap<>();
public void selectAll() throws Exception {

        String SqlStatement = null;

        if (ds == null) {
            throw new SQLException();
        }

        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        if (conn == null) {
            throw new SQLException();
        }

        SqlStatement = "SELECT ID FROM ACTIVESESSIONSLOG";

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        int count = 0;

        try {
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            boolean committed = false;
            try {
                ps = conn.prepareStatement(SqlStatement);
                resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
                selected.clear();

                while (resultSet.next()) {

                    selected.put(resultSet.getString("ID"), true);
                }
/*
                for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> entry : selectedIds.entrySet()) {
                    entry.setValue(true);
                }

*/                conn.commit();
                committed = true;
            } finally {
                if (!committed) {
                    conn.rollback();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            ps.close();
            conn.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`<f:ajax>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html) to send an ajax request.

```html
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.selectAll}" onclick="highlight(this)" class="checkall">
    <f:ajax listener="#{bean.onSelectAll}" render="@form" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

with

```
private boolean selectAll;

public void onSelectAll(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    // If you're using a boolean property on the row object.
    for (Item item : list) {
        item.setSelected(selectAll);
    }

    // Or if you're using a Map<Long, Boolean> on item IDs
    for (Entry<Long, Boolean> entry : selected.entrySet()) {
        entry.setValue(selectAll);
    }
}

public boolean isSelectAll() {
    return selectAll;
}

public void setSelectAll(boolean selectAll) {
    this.selectAll = selectAll;
}
```

Ideally the bean should be placed in the view scope by `@ViewScoped` to keep it alive across the ajax requests on the same view.

Don't use `binding` to a bean property unless you have a *very good* reason. It's intented to bind the whole `UIComponent` to the bean which allows dynamic component manipulation, but more than often there are simpler and less obtrusive ways.

Comment: Thank you! May I ask you one more question: The code works when I select the checkbox. But how I can call the Java method `uncheckAll` when I deselect the checkbox?

Comment: Just check the value of `selectAll` inside the `onSelectAll()` method if it's `true` or `false`. I've edited the answer with an example implementation of the `onSelectAll()` method. Hopefully that's self-explaining enough.

Comment: I'm using a slightly different approach. I suppose that in my case I have to change the Boolean value? It will be a lot easy if I can call a second java method which just changes the hashmap values.

Comment: Yes, change it with the value of `selectAll`. All that DB interaction logic is however strange. You're supposed to have the list of items already at your hands. The list of items should be already loaded in (post)constructor of the view scoped managed bean.

Comment: I use lazy loading. It's not possible to have all the ID's without SQL statement and hashmap.

Comment: Well, that might indicate that your bean is "doing too much". But anyway, just set the map value with the value of `selectAll`, yes :)

Comment: I'm not aware in this case how I can send the Boolean value from the `h:selectBooleanCheckbox` to the backing bean.

Comment: The example in my answer already shows that. It's the `selectAll` property which is bound by `value="#{bean.selectAll}"`.

Comment: I get this error: XML Parsing Error: unclosed CDATA section Location: moz-nullprincipal:{8d3af59f-f323-44c5-a81e-b8c60bdca647} Line Number 138, Column 112:

....IllegalStateException</error-name><error-message
...-------------------------------------------------^

Comment: the solutions is `private boolean selectAll = false;`. Thank you for the help.